# DecorationView gets resized when AutoSizing cells are enabled in UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

*Environment:*
`UICollectionView` that looks like UITableView
Custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass to define the `frame` of the `DecorationView`
Self-Sizing cells enabled

*Expected behavior:*
A `DecorationView` that should be placed as a background for every section of the `UICollectionView`

[image: Expected Behavior]

*Observed Behavior:*
The `DecorationView` collapses to an arbitrary size:

[image: Observed Behavior]

Seems that `UICollectionView` tries to calculate an automatic size for the `DecorationView`. If I disable Self-Sizing cells, the decoration view is being placed exactly at the expected place.

**Is there any way to disable Self-Sizing for `DecorationView` ?**

In my `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass I simply take the first and last cells in the section and stretch the background to fill the space underneath them. The problem is that `UICollectionView` does not respect the size calculated there:

```
override func layoutAttributesForDecorationView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
      return nil
    }

    let section = indexPath.section
    let attrs = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forDecorationViewOfKind: backgroundViewClass.reuseIdentifier(),
                                                 with: indexPath)
    let numberOfItems = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)
    let lastIndex = numberOfItems - 1

    guard let firstItemAttributes = layoutAttributesForItem(at: IndexPath(indexes: [section, 0])),
      let lastItemAttributes = layoutAttributesForItem(at: IndexPath(indexes: [section, lastIndex])) else {
        return nil
    }

    let startFrame = firstItemAttributes.frame
    let endFrame = lastItemAttributes.frame

    let origin = startFrame.origin
    let size = CGSize(width: startFrame.width,
                      height: -startFrame.minY + endFrame.maxY)

    let frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
    attrs.frame = frame
    attrs.zIndex = -1

    return attrs
}
```

Comment: Could you post a demo on GitHub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible that the frames of your decoration views are not being updated (i.e. invalidated) after the frames of your cells have been self-sized. The result is that the width of each decoration view remains at its default size.

Try implementing this function, which should invalidate the layout of the decoration view for each section every time the layout of an item in that section is invalidated:

```
override func invalidateLayout(with context: UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext) {
    let invalidatedSections = context.invalidatedItemIndexPaths?.map { $0.section } ?? []
    let decorationIndexPaths = invalidatedSections.map { IndexPath(item: 0, section: $0) }
    context.invalidateDecorationElements(ofKind: backgroundViewClass.reuseIdentifier(), at: decorationIndexPaths)
    super.invalidateLayout(with: context)
}
```

Comment: While I haven't tested your solution yet, it looks like the most promising, I'll definitely give it a try.

Because of this problem, I decided not to go with the self-sizing cells for now.